# Need help connecting a Pixel 3xl on Android 11 to a Sony ax5000

Tags: android-auto

Wondering if anyone has any troubleshooting tips for my problem. I have a pixel 3 XL that is running up to date android auto and Android.

When attempting to connect my pixel 3xl to my Sony ax5000 head unit, my phone doesn't seem to recognize that it is connected to an android auto cable. I'm fairly confident everything is fine with the head unit and cable, as my wife's phone (a Samsung) and other devices are able to detect and connect to the device without problem using the same and other cables. Because nothing is ever prompted, I don't have any more ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue. Do you have any suggestions?

I went to check the default USB configuration in the developer options and confirmed it is set to File Transfer / Android Auto. Are there other settings there (or anywhere else) I should check?

Thanks!